# How can i query to get to this result?

Tags: sql, azure

```
id     string     id2  
1        a         1
2        b         1
3        a         2
4        c         2
5        d         3
```

Ok, so i can get `SELECT * FROM table WHERE string NOT IN ('a','c')`:

```
2        b         1
5        d         3
```

but i also want to not get the rest of the rows that contain a or c with the same id2.
result:

```
5        d         3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id2 = t.id2 and t2.string in ('A', 'C')
                 );
```

If you just want the `id2` values, you might find aggregation convenient:

```
select id2
from t
group by id2
having sum(case when string in ('A', 'C') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but i've been trying a lot to convert the query to linq and i'm getting only incorrect results.

Comment: @PuscasuAndrei . . . I'm not so good with linq.  You might want to ask another question.  Be sure to tag it with `linq` and include the query that you want transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a subquery that returns the id2 values having a or c. Do `NOT IN` those id2 values.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id2 not in (select id2 from table where string IN ('a','c'))
```

If id2 can contain null values, do `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from table t2
                  where t2.string IN ('a','c')
                    and t1.id2 = t2.id2))
```